# Distinguish between my LinkedList implementation and java built in LinkedList class

Tags: java, class, linked-list

I have a program (program.java) in a folder that uses the LinkedList class, and uses .get(), .add(), etc. methods. I also have a LinkedList program in that folder that has my own implementation of LinkedLists. When I use one of the built in LinkedList methods (.get(), .add(), etc) in program.java, I get an error saying that these methods cannot be found. This is because it's looking for these methods in my own LinkedList implementation.

I know that both my LinkedList implementation and the built in LinkedList class have the same class name, but is this the reason that program.java isn't finding the built in LinkedList methods? Should I just name my LinkedList implementation a different class name - perhaps LinkedList_me?

Comment: Show your code and your error message please. But yes, it sounds like you need to disambiguate your class names, either by renaming yours, or avoiding the JDK's, or using the fully qualified name (`java.util.LinkedList`).

Comment: @shmosel Okay, importing the LinkedList class separately worked. I was originally importing (java.util.*).

Comment: One thing you could do is move your `LinkedList` implementation to a separate package, and only import it when you need to.  So use `import yourpackage.LinkedList;` when you want your one, and `import java.util.LinkedList` when you want the JDK one.  Also, never use `*` in an `import` statement, because it leads to problems of precisely this kind.

Answer (score 0):

Importing the fully qualified name (`java.util.LinkedList`) on its own instead of (`java.util.*`) did the trick.